# How many of your "breathe" you took for granted so far?

Tags: verbs, nouns

How many of your "breathe" you took for granted so far?

"how many" with breathe.. would go right?

How to construct the sentence more punchier way?

Comment: *How many* cannot be used with *breathe*, because *breathe* is a verb. The noun is *breath*.

Comment: How many breaths in your life have you taken for granted?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure, what you mean by a 'punchier' way. But the use of 'breathe' there is incorrect as said in comments.

> [Breathe (v)](http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/BREATHE) - *draw air into, and out of, the lungs.* AND 
>   [Breath (n)](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=breath) - *The process of taking in and expelling air during breathing.*

*How many* here should go with countable nouns. So, the correct sentence, as Jim stated, would be...

> How many breaths in your life have you taken for granted?

Comment: Rather, "How many breaths in your life _have_ you taken for granted?".

Comment: @army you may choose this as the answer if it has satisfied you. You would probably close this to maintain this site.